# Can I make knockout generate bindings from the values in other bindings?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365253/how-do-i-update-this-to-use-the-latest-version-of-bootstrap) and getting an answer I have a modal form which has its contents data bound to a knockout model.  this is great and makes it generic and reusable, so long as the form follows the same pattern as template, ie a couple of buttons and a fixed body.

What I would like is to make the body dynamic and contain input fields bound to other values on my view model.

So I have this:

```
<script id="myModal" type="text/html">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click:close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 data-bind="html:header"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: paramName" /><br/>
                Type:<input type="text" data-bind="value: paramType" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind="click:close,html:closeLabel"></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:action,html:primaryLabel"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

which extends the form to include a couple of text input fields.  Can I make this body content so that it is still populated from my view model, but still has the data-bindings.  So have a vierw model that looks like this:

```
modal = {
    header: ko.observable("This is a modal"),
    body: ko.observable("Name:<input type='text' data-bind='value: paramName' /><br/>Type:<input type='text' data-bind='value: paramType' /><br />"),
    paramName: ko.observable(),
    paramType: ko.observable(),
    closeLabel: "Cancel",
    primaryLabel: "Ok",
    show: ko.observable(false), /* Set to true to show initially */
    onClose: function () {
        self.onModalClose();
    },
    onAction: function () {
        if (self.modal.paramName() && self.modal.paramType()) {
            self.nextParameter.name(self.modal.paramName());
            self.nextParameter.type(self.modal.paramType());
            self.addInputParameter();
            self.modal.show(false);
        }            
    }
```

and have the template go back to being generic like this

```
<script id="myModal" type="text/html">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click:close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 data-bind="html:header"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-bind"html: body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind="click:close,html:closeLabel"></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:action,html:primaryLabel"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

but still have knockout bind changes to the first input to `paramName` and changes to the second input to `paramType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this with a dynamic template, as described in note 5 [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).  So it would look something like this:

```
modal = {
    header: ko.observable("This is a modal"),
    //this is now just the name of the template
    body: ko.observable('bodyTemplateA'),
    // ...
};
```

And then in your binding, do

```
<div class="modal-body" data-bind="template: { name: body }">
</div>
```

and then of course define all of your needed templates separately:

```
<script id="bodyTemplateA" type="text/html">
     Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: paramName" /><br/>
     Type:<input type="text" data-bind="value: paramType" /><br />
</script>
```

Not quite what you were looking for, but I think that'll be a lot easier and maintainable than trying to keep all your various ko-bound html in strings throughout your code.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this sounds like a much better idea than what I was trying to do :), I'll give it a go

Comment: Using templates is likely the best way to go (and you could also create or load new templates dynamically if you want to, there are several tutorials on the net). Just for completeness I would like to add that the `html` bindingHandler is explicitly made not to handle child bindings. It even states in a comment in [the code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/html.js) that it intends to "Prevent binding on the dynamically-injected HTML (as developers are unlikely to expect that, and it has security implications)".

Comment: This works great, much appreciated.  And thanks for the note @robertwesterlund, I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: @AdamRackis this is great, only one problem which is how I can get autofocus into one of my inputs in the script template to work in IE.  `hasfocus: true` doesn't seem to work in the binding

Comment: @Sam - not sure.  I'd open a fresh question and see if someone can help you on that.

Comment: yeah I'd already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547472/how-can-i-get-auto-focus-to-an-input-element-in-a-dynamically-generated-knockout?noredirect=1#comment34317157_22547472) but forgot to post a link